# How can i use internal iteration within function in python?

Tags: python

I need this code to run :

```
pp = ["first", "second", "third"]
sum(d for d in pp)
```

I get the `error`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I guess there is something to do with lazy evaluation. Could you please help me with this?

thank you!

Comment: `sum` defaults to starting from an initial sum of `0`, and even if you try to change that, it will specifically refuse to sum strings (because summing strings with `sum` is a terrible idea and `''.join` is far more efficient).

Comment: Lazy evaluation has nothing to do with this.

Comment: if you type `help(sum)` in your python interpreter, it will tell you that parameters to the builtin sum function cannot be strings. So that is the first problem with this code. You can use `''.join(pp)` to join strings if that is what your objective is.

Comment: How do you expect strings to be summable?  Are you expecting it to magically translate `first` to `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum()` buildin function that is by default `start` is `0`. It takes only numbers and return the total. It is not allowed `string`. So, you get above `error`. Rather,  you can join the list using `''.join()` function.

Like :

```
pp = ["first", "second", "third"]
sum = ''.join(pp)
print(sum)
```

Output :

```
firstsecondthird
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. **`start` defaults to 0. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string**.

By default `start` is `0` and it is an integer. `sum(d for d in pp)` try to sum up integer with string.